# Qt database error due to QSqlQuery object scope

Tags: qt, scope, qtsql

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QApplication>

class   ABC {
public:
    QSqlDatabase db;
    QSqlQuery memberQuery;

    ABC() {
        db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        db.setDatabaseName("test");
        qDebug() << "Database open test : " << db.open();

    }

    void    database() {
        qDebug() << "Inside database method..." << endl;
        QSqlQuery localQuery ;
        qDebug() << "Using local Query : " << localQuery.exec("create table if not exists alu (ini int)");
        localQuery.clear();

        qDebug() << "Using memeber query object: " << memberQuery.exec("create table if not exists alu (ini int)");
        memberQuery.clear();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ABC ob;
    ob.database();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Following result is found after executing this code.

```
Database open test :  true 
Inside database method... 

Using local Query :  true 
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
Using memeber query object:  false
```

My question is why can't I use a member object QSqlQuery instead of a local one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialise your `QSqlQuery` using the `QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase db)` constructor.

To do this you will need to use initialiser lists in the constructor and have already setup the DB connection, or use pointers to initialise the `QSqlQuery` later.

With an `ABC` constructor taking an initialised DB (create the DB in main):

```
ABC(QSqlDatabase _db) :
  db(_db),
  memberQuery(db)
{
  Q_ASSERT(db.isOpen());
}
```

Or

```
class ABC
{
  QSqlDatabase db;
  QSqlQuery* memberQueryPtr;

  public:
    ABC() : db(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE")),memberQueryPtr(0)
    {
      db.setDatabaseName("test");
      if (!db.open())
        return;
      memberQueryPtr = new QSqlQuery(db);
    }

    ~ABC()
    {
      delete memberQueryPtr; memberQueryPtr = 0;
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Then why does the local object work witout initializaing with db?

Comment: It works because after adding the database, it becomes the default connection, so any `QSqlQuery`created thereafter will use it. When using a class property, the QSqlQuery is instantiated BEFORE creating the default db connection.